# call masm function with arguments from c++ code

Tags: c++, assembly, masm

here is assembler code:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall

_asmFunc proto arg1: dword, arg2: dword

.data
.code

_asmFunc proc, arg1: dword, arg2:dword
    mov eax, arg1
    add eax, arg2
    ret
_asmFunc endp

end
```

and here is c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" int asmFunc(int, int);

int main()
{
    std::cout << asmFunc(5, 6);

    char a;
    std::cin >> a;
    return 0;
}
```

the thing is: in case i remove all arguments from function, remove stdcall from model in asm and remove proto line - i can call this from c++, but if i want to pass some arguments, i need to add them after procedure header, which means i need to add stdcall, in this case c++ tells me that program can't find my function (unresolved external symbol _asmFunc), i really can't find any normal combination (cause i don't wanna pass arguments by hand via registers or manually put them in stack and take them out in my function, too many extra code) that allows me to call asm function with arguments from c++, either it can't have arguments or c++ code can't find it

Comment: Your C++ and assembly code need to agree on a calling convention. Use `.model flat, c` in your assembly code, or add `__attribute__((__stdcall__))` to the function declaration in your C++ code.

Comment: my bad, forgot to mention it, i tried both, in case of adding model flat, c instead of model flat, stdcall changes nothing, c++ still can't find the function (in c++ code tried adding __cdecl, __stdcall and nothing, none of this helped), in terms of model flat, stdcall tried too adding to c++ code all three variants - none helped, only change is in case of both asm and c++ code has model flat, stdcall and __stdcall - function name in error message becomes _asmFunc@8 instead of just _asmFunc, haven't managed to fix this error either

Comment: You shouldn't add an underscore to the name yourself. MASM does that for you.

Comment: thanks man, didn't know that detail, u r awesome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The calling convention in the `.model` directive must match the calling convention in the C function declaration. For the default `cdecl` calling convention, just use `.model flat, c`
2. As a result of specifying the language type in the [`.model`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-model?view=vs-2019) directive, name decoration is performed automatically. This means you should not add any name decoration like `_` to the names, those will be decorated according to the [name mangling rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names?view=vs-2019) for the specified calling convention.

Answer (score 0):

function name in asm code should be without _ in beginning, asm adds underscore itself